# How to search 2 words in a text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, search, contains, indexof

I need to find `2` or more words in a text.
For example:
 I have a XML file and I need to search a name, eg `"Manoel Silva"`. The full name in the XML is `"Manoel da Silva"`.

So, I need to find the words in the XML. If I search by `"Manoel da Silva"`, I found the name but if I search only `"Manoel Silva"` I don't find :(

```
.....
$(xml).find('dado').each(function() {
            var doc      = $(this).find('doc').text(),
                razao    = $(this).find('razao').text(),
                fantasia = $(this).find('fantasia').text(),
                cidade   = $(this).find('cidade').text(),
                uf       = $(this).find('uf').text();

                var regex = new RegExp(razao, "g");
                var test = regex.test(nomeFiltro);
                console.log(test);

            window.indexN = razao.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro);
......
```

Comment: Please translate your code snippet so it is readable by other community members.

Comment: I think it is not necessary... razao = company name / nomeFiltro = nameForm / dado = data

Comment: It should be more readable if your write labels in the original thread. Reader won't crawl to comments to find what the variables are referring to.

Comment: @tmarwen what difference does it make what the variable and tag names are?

Comment: @MaiconFurtado your regex is looking for exact match. If you want word matches you would have to split words and test each. Not 100% clear what search criteria is

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var names = razao.split(' ');
var snames = names[0] + '(' + names[1] + ')' + (names.length == 2 ? '{1}' : '{0}' + names[2]); 

var regex = new RegExp(snames, "g");
var test = regex.test(nomeFiltro);
console.log(test);
```